# HP DM4-3060EF Beats Edition - Will it be all ok with ubuntu?

Tags: hp

I will have in a few days this laptop (HP DM4-3060EF Beats Edition) and I want to know if all is working with it. For example, how about HP coolsense ?

Does anybody else have the same laptop ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop, been running 12.04 for 5 months or so, all running well, although it took a long time to get the broadcom drivers to work properly, and I think they still don't- connection to APs takes a long time.
 The fingerprint reader has no drivers, and the graphics card drivers need to be installed from the manufacturer, but there is a linux driver.
Switche-able graphics never worked right, but I dont care about that so much- usually plugged in.
Upgrading to 12.10 alpha today, same problems with broadcom, installing graphics now, everything else works(have given up on the fingerprint sensor)

Overall performance is good, smooth ride.

Paul

P.S- Since writing this things have come to light, wireless seems to work out the box, the ATI card has no support- so intel sandybidge is used- but the ATI card is still powered; causing the laptop to overheat and the fan to constantly run (reducing battery)- edit rc.local and add "echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch" to work arouond this.. it's been more than a year and no fix yet...

Also the subwoofer isn't activated because the hd sound model isn't supported- I initially used the model for the dm7 (in alsabase), but this doesnt seem to work in 13.10- if it works for you you need to swap the channels for the front speakers and the subwoofers afterwards...

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Well. Ok i have installed ubuntu on my new laptop. Installation went well and all seems to work ?
I don't know if it is all working as good as in windows (for the sound for example) but it's working quiet well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Everything I read seems to say that Linux will install ok, but that some people were

1. having an issue with occasional freezing, and
2. trackpad might be picky
3. keyboard issues might need to be resolved with a bios update (in W7).

Out of curiosity, do you notice any of these issues?

Comment: Hello, Nothing like this. The only problem for is the fan that are a little bit noisy. I think updating the bios could help but as i have uninstalled Windows I can't do aything.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Instead of asking for a wild guess, you could try to run a [liveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) version of Ubuntu, without the need of formatting your hard drive, uninstalling your current Operating System, or falling back to techniques like dual boot, in order to get a good taste of how Ubuntu will run on your computer.